# Build Failed while 'run android' : unable to resolve class com.android.build.OutputFile @ line 3, column 1. import com.android.build.OutputFile

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

So I just created a react native app 'tracks' using **'$ npx react-native init tracks'** and when I try to run the command **'$ npx react-native run-android'**, it shows the following error. I 've tried changing the class path gradle version (default 4.2.2) to many other versions, but of no use.
I haven't been able to get around it for days. Please help**

**CMD:**

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 871 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\utsar\Desktop\ReactProjects\tracks\android\app\build.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file 'C:\Users\utsar\Desktop\ReactProjects\tracks\android\app\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file 'C:\Users\utsar\Desktop\ReactProjects\tracks\android\app\build.gradle': 3: unable to resolve class com.android.build.OutputFile
   @ line 3, column 1.
     import com.android.build.OutputFile
     ^

  1 error


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\utsar\Desktop\ReactProjects\tracks\android\app\build.gradle' line: 3

* What went wrong:
Could not compile build file 'C:\Users\utsar\Desktop\ReactProjects\tracks\android\app\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file 'C:\Users\utsar\Desktop\ReactProjects\tracks\android\app\build.gradle': 3: unable to resolve class com.android.build.OutputFile
   @ line 3, column 1.
     import com.android.build.OutputFile
     ^

  1 error


* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s

    at makeError (C:\Users\utsar\Desktop\ReactProjects\tracks\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\utsar\Desktop\ReactProjects\tracks\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\utsar\Desktop\ReactProjects\tracks\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:106:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\utsar\Desktop\ReactProjects\tracks\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Answer (score 0):

Best help I can give is that if your build.gradle file doesn't apply the android plugin it won't be able to resolve the import "com.android.build.OutputFile".

Your gradle file that uses "com.android.build.OutputFile" needs this line:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

This line should only be added to the app module level build file.

Unfortunately I don't know much react native. I'm only answering from how I solved this issue when I encountered it on a normal project.